# connecting to database - connectionString connect.Open() error

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2013

So I am trying to run a query in a database that searches the database table from a `textbox` input. My code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Query
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void employeeBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.employeeBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.personnelDataSet);

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'personnelDataSet.employee' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.employeeTableAdapter.Fill(this.personnelDataSet.employee);

        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        string connectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;";

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string commandText = "SELECT employeeID, name, position, hourlyPayRate " +
                     "FROM dbo.employee WHERE name LIKE '%'+ @Name + '%'";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //Create a SqlCommand instance
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
                //Add the parameter
                command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox1.Text;

                //Execute the query
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch
                {
                    //Handle excepetion, show message to user...
                    MessageBox.Show("Error bitch!");
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I take the catch out I can see the error occurs at `connection.Open()`. The error takes a while to happen which makes me wonder whether there is an issue with `string connectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;";`

This is the error that I receive:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
```

Comment: its probably your connection string that is broken. Have you got ssms? Can you verify your connection string?

Comment: I don't have ssms. How could I go about verifying it?

Comment: It is your connectionstring. You have just taken the regular connectionstring through copy-paste. Actually fill in the serveraddress etc.

Comment: Why don't you replace catch with catch(SqlException ex) and then add to your MessageBox.Show("Error bitch!"+ ex.ToString();

This will give you more information on what is going wrong.

Comment: @Ravendarksky Yeah I wasn't planning on actually leaving it at error bitch, but noted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate the connection string. If `Open()` is throwing an `SqlException` then the connection string is invalid. To enable you to establish the exact form of the connection string you require, take a look at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

As to why the exception is showing as unhanded, you need to 'consume' the exception as follows:

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Handle excepetion, show message to user...
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot with the exception. I just don't know how I would go about validating the connection string?

Comment: Hi Matt, What are you attempting to connect to? See edit for a link to connectionstrings.com, this should help you obtain the correct form of connection string for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
  string connectionString = "Server=.\InstanceName;Database=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True;";
```

Also

```
string commandText = "SELECT employeeID, name, position, hourlyPayRate 
                     FROM dbo.employee WHERE name LIKE '%@Name%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 string connectionString = "Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User id=myUser;Password=myPAss;Connect Timeout=15;Integrated Security=false";
```

Comment: This is definitely not going to help resolve the connection string problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your connection string inside the event.

An alternate method is to link your database through web.config as follows:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

And then the connection string can be as:

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBName"].ConnectionString;
```